# Why can't I use %USERPROFILE% in %PATH%?

Tags: windows, command-line, path, environment-variables

On my Windows 7 machine, using the *System Properties > Environment Variables* tool, I try to add `%USERPROFILE%\Bin` to the system variable `PATH`. For some reason, that doesn't work, even though `%SystemRoot%\system32` works fine.

When I try to run commands from the console, files in my Bin folder are not found, even though files in the `System32` folder are found.

The only difference between `UserProfile` and `SystemRoot` that I can see is that the former is a user variable while the latter is a system variable.

`echo %USERPROFILE%\Bin` yields `c:\Users\zano`, and if I add `c:\Users\zano\Bin` explicitly, everything work fine.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

System variables are set before user variables are. Consequently, at the time system variables are being set, none of your user variables exist yet.

You may be able to create a new user variable called PATH and set it to "`%USERPROFILE%\Bin;%PATH%`". I have not tested it, but it *may* do what you want. USERPROFILE might still not be set, though, so you might need to hard-code the path into your user variable, but at least it won't affect other users on the computer.

Answer (score 5):

Stephen Jennings was right, but just a little clarity. In Windows, if the User variable Path exists, it is automatically appended to the System variable Path.  The User variable Path is permitted to use %UserProfile% while the System variable gets the literal text "%UserProfile%".

So creating User variable "Path" and setting it to %UserProfile%\Bin was all that was needed.

Example 1:

System Variable Path = C:\WINDOWS\
User Variable Path = %UserProfile%\Bin

User's path will be

C:\WINDOWS;C:\Users\User\Bin

Example 2:

System Variable Path = C:\WINDOWS\;%UserProfile%\Bin

User Variable Path is not set at all.

User's path will be

C:\WINDOWS\;%UserProfile%\Bin

You don't want Example 2.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to what Stephen said but

Create a user environment variable called PATH
Within this you can use %USERPROFILE% correctly - USERPROFILE is expanded before user section is processed.
This user PATH will be automatically appended to the system path so no need to add the %PATH% part.

e.g.

System variable: PATH=c:\path1
User variable PATH=%USERPROFILE%\path2

Resulting path: PATH=c:\path1;C:\Users\myuser\path2